# Most fitting word for a time interval with specific start and end?

Tags: single-word-requests

If I'm talking about an appointment of a *specific* time and duration, what's the most fitting word? "Time span", "time range", "time interval"? Anything else?

By "most fitting" I mean that it should suggest to the listener that I'm talking about the interval between specific dates, not about a duration or period.

[Word for a moment in time defined with beginning and end](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/148470/word-for-a-moment-in-time-defined-with-beginning-and-end) only has a rather pragmatic answer concerning programming.

Online dictionaries give contradicting definitions, for example for "time interval":

http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/time%20interval "a definite length of time marked off by two instants."

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/time+interval "Duration of a segment of time without reference to when the time interval begins or ends."

Comment: They give conflicting definitions because the term is used in different ways. If it is important enough, you will have to give the actual beginning and end times.

Comment: Can you please provide an example sentence with ______ where the word or phrase would be placed?  Otherwise, I'm not sure I'm getting your meaning.

Comment: @KristinaLopez "Your appointment is from 10 AM to 2 PM. During that _____, you will be...". Here any word would do ("period", for example), because the meaning is clear from context. My concern is that if there were a few sentences interposed between the appointment and the ___, "period" might be less clear - am I talking about the duration or *that* exact appointment? The question comes from a technical writing perspective where my writing is supposed to be clear and short. In prose, I have more possibilities to express myself clearly.

Comment: As long as there is only the single appointment in the paragraph, for example, I imagine you could use "appointment" or "2-hour appointment" to satisfy your need to clarify and define that period.

Comment: *Duration* or *time interval*, both of which you mentioned. *Duration* generally refers directly or indirectly to something that occurred during the period in question.

Comment: *Session* implies a dedicated interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps he is suggesting at 'Time schedule' or 'time calendar'.

I think,"TIME SLOT" would be most befitting which actually,amongst others, goes to mean the allocated time for an aircraft's departure or arrival at an airport's runway.

Answer (score 0):

"Period between" comes to mind.

I.e, "In the period between starting and finishing college, I got to know many professors."

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the original question, the issue is to make sure it's clear that the word or phrase specifically references the appointment details stated at the begin, after some intervening text that might otherwise fuzz the reader's ability to make the connection.

I would handle this in the following way.

1. Begin by saying "Your Appointment Period is from 10 a.m. to 2 p.m.". Here, "Appointment Period" will hopefully be recognised (and later remembered) as a term that is being defined. Using capitals in this way is a useful way of emphasising this role as a definition with a special meaning.
2. Later in the text, refer to this consistently as the Appointment Period. The reader will recognise this as the definition set up earlier in the text. If some pages intervene, you could even go a step further and say "the Appointment Period shown on page *x*".

Note: *Appointment Period* is just an example; my answer is more about making sure the reader is clear what earlier text is referred to, rather than about the turn of phrase, of which most of those suggested so far would work but would not solve the reference issue.